# Mvc Razor Scripting Values from DDL to Actionlink

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Vs'12 Asp.net C# MVC4, Internet Application Tempalte

I'm attempting to write a `<script>` for my dropdownlist to change an actionlink's information.

what i have sofar

```
 function select_prospect() {
    //Handle the select event

    $('#YourActionLinkName')val() = $("#Prospects").val();

    var val = $("#Clients").val();
    var href = "/Prospect/Index/" + val;
    this.href = ""; //clears out old href for reuse
    this.href = href; //changes href value to currently slected dropdown value
}
```

I am attempting to grab my Actionlink by ID / Name and then change its values and adding the corresponding hrefs with the ones from the dropdown.
What am i doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

Per Ufuks answer *I have attempted this code*

```
$('#YourActionLinkName').val(
  $("#Prospects").val(),
  this.href = "/Prospect/Create/" + $("#Prospects").val()
);
```

at the bottom of the page in < script > wich still does not update my actionlink correctly. Ideas?

Comment: None its not setting the values, I assume thats because I am new to <script> that somehow I'm doing it wrong syntax wise?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not how you use the `val` function

```
$('#YourActionLinkName').val() = $("#Prospects").val();
```

It should be like this:

```
$('#YourActionLinkName').val($("#Prospects").val());
```

Comment: I didn't catch that because of the way it was formatted, good eye!

Comment: That was the only problem?

Comment: @UfukHacıoğulları Can you please look at the updated code above? thanks

Comment: @DonThomasBoyle val doesn't take two parameters and it only works for input elements.

Comment: @DonThomasBoyle You need to use [html](http://api.jquery.com/html/) function to replace link text.